# Want to write XML Note with attribute only for parent node.

Tags: xml, vb.net, vb.net-2010

I want to write the XML file with the attribute for parent node...
(in VB.NET)
I know how to write XML nodes but I haven't write XML node with attributes...
How to write it ? 
I have written below code but stuck on how write Node with attribute...

```
        xmlWriter__1 = XmlWriter.Create("C:\Data\Trial1.xml)

        xmlWriter__1.WriteStartDocument()

        xmlWriter__1.WriteStartElement("Data")

        xmlWriter__1.WriteStartElement("Trial")



        xmlWriter__1.WriteStartElement("FlatAllocation")
        'Flat Name String 

        xmlWriter__1.WriteStartElement("FlatName")

        xmlWriter__1.WriteString(Convert.ToString(FlatString))

        xmlWriter__1.WriteEndElement()

        'ID
        xmlWriter__1.WriteStartElement("CatID")

        xmlWriter__1.WriteString(Convert.ToString(catId))

        xmlWriter__1.WriteEndElement()

        xmlWriter__1.WriteEndDocument()

        xmlWriter__1.Close()
```

I want to write below XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data>
<Trial No="1">
  <FlatAllocation>
    <FlatName>115</FlatName>
    <CatID>1</CatID>
  </FlatAllocation>
</Trial>
<Trial No="2">
  <FlatAllocation>
    <FlatName>A/1###108</FlatName>
    <CatID>1</CatID>
  </FlatAllocation>
  <FlatAllocation>
    <FlatName>A/2###10688</FlatName>
    <CatID>1</CatID>
  </FlatAllocation>
</Trial>
</Data>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
xmlWriter__1 = XmlWriter.Create("C:\Data\Trial1.xml)
xmlWriter__1.WriteStartDocument()
xmlWriter__1.WriteStartElement("Data")
xmlWriter__1.WriteStartElement("Trial")

'add this after the Trial element
xmlWriter__1.WriteAttributeString("No", "1");

xmlWriter__1.WriteStartElement("FlatAllocation")
'Flat Name String 
xmlWriter__1.WriteStartElement("FlatName")
xmlWriter__1.WriteString(Convert.ToString(FlatString))
xmlWriter__1.WriteEndElement()
'ID
xmlWriter__1.WriteStartElement("CatID")
xmlWriter__1.WriteString(Convert.ToString(catId))
xmlWriter__1.WriteEndElement()
xmlWriter__1.WriteEndDocument()
xmlWriter__1.Close()
```

and for further information take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.aspx